# Is it possible to remove the projectors lighting that's imprinted on the staff members

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, image-manipulation

As you can see display screen is imprinted on the faces of around 5 members. I was wondering whether it is possible to remove the lighting. Either through clone stamp, feathering or any other way. I am not quite sure.

I have taken another photo were the display was off. But the student's were not around. As a student, I have offered to help the staff members in media production, however I now feel bad about this issue. I am still learning Photoshop and want to remove the lighting on the faces of the 5 members on the picture.

Thank you so much guys. I finally got it working. This might be a rude request, but I don't expect it to happen. Would it be possible to delete the question, or at least the images. Since I was not given permission to post them here. I don't want to get in trouble for posting something were it does not belong.
If not then let's pray they don't find them. :)

Thanks again.

Comment: @SaliWarrior. Take this as an experience, when you are taking a group shoot you are the commander. So look around, look the environment, the people, the best spot stand, and turn off the projector.

Comment: I think if you were to flag and it goot enough flags then the moderator will look at it. However Instead of deleting the question which is a bit unfair. What about the pictures. If you guys can go on edit and remove the link will the photo's disappear.

Comment: Given the effort in all the answers, which largely depend on use of the images, I'd be reluctant to remove the images, much less the entire answer, as the answers could be very useful to other people.

Comment: If you click on the contact link at the bottom of the page and describe the problem, it's possible you could have your profile disassociated from the question (the question would attributed to "Anonymous")

Comment: If you want to create a post on meta (https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/) I and others could comment further.

Answer (score 4):

The best option for you is to clone from the other image.

And if done correctly, no one will know that you edited the image.

Open the image in photoshop

[image]

Next, open the other image in photoshop as a separate file

Select just the portion of the image that needs to be cloned

[image]

**Drag that selection into the main image**

[image]

Cmd or Ctrl T to bring up the transform options

Now, use the warp tool to align the images

[image]

Next, create a mask and invert it and paint in white

[image]

Repeat this process for all the others – Should only take about 5 minutes per person.

Fortunately for you, they are all available in the good picture.

As for the people with the highlights on the forehead

Make a selection on the NON- Highlighted area,

Then using the Transform Option, flip horizontal

[image]

Align it to the side with the highlight

Create a mask and invert it.

Now brush the area with white

[image]

I have left the projector light on, but if you want that removed, you will need to make bigger selections and then use Blend-if to get an even tone

Hope this helps

**Edit**

Had a play and it was little more challenging than at first anticipated.

The guy with the long hair had to be cloned in completely without warp.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. So I have reached the point where I managed to blend the first person but I don't understand the mask and invert part. I added the mask layer and it was automatically white. I didn't have to paint it. Also where do I find the invert? It's been two years since I last used photoshop. Sorry.

Comment: Whilst the mask is selected, CMD or Ctrl "I" will invert the mask. It will go from white to black. Now select the brush tool and ensure that white is selected as your foreground color. Remember, white reveals what's under the mask and black hides. Good luck

Comment: @SaliWarrior - I have added a complete edit so you have something as a reference

Answer (score 1):

Probably a good approach would be to clone the teachers over the other photo. But one student will still remain affected.

Mask the faces on the second photo, copy > and paste on the first image.

Here is a rough test.

[image]

And here is a surreal image of the objects. It is a simple matter of masking coping pasting and adjusting the curves to match the luminosity.

[image]

The poor kid on the left needs an additional makeup.

---

If you had not the other photo it would be almost impossible to heal the image.

Take this as an experience, when you are taking a group shoot you are the commander. So look around, look at the environment, the people, the best spot stand, and turn off the projector!

Comment: Thank you so much. How long did it take you?

Comment: Like 20 mins (5 mins per head) The most boring part is the masking of the heads. Use @Abdul Quraishi method. I posted my answer at the "same time".

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult one...

I've had a quick, ***very*** rough & ready go at just one of the guys in the light.
First I duplicated the layer, so we can have a mainly untouched layer underneath.
Then I made a selection round him [so scrappy I missed an ear & caught a bit too much suit... I did say this was very quick]
I added a mask & left only that part visible.
A little brightness/contrast to match his suit to the unlit portion & some Colour Range selection to try grab the purple writing [this would need two separate attempts, one for over his suit & another for over his skin, which I didn't do] & rebalance the purple to be less obvious.

Range select -

[image]

Rough lasso & before/after comparison -

[image]
[image]

To improve on this abysmal attempt, you can refine your lasso edges & feather your mask in. Spend longer getting the colour range & the detail of how you adapt the colours.

From comments - trying to do the entire projector area doesn't really work so well, it rapidly collapses to something like this...

[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAMlm.png)

Comment: It might be easier, and look more natural, to select the entire area affected by the projected light to reduce its intensity, rather than attempt to completely remove it.

Comment: It doesn't really work - that was my first guess too, but I'll add what very quickly happens if you try to do it as a 'one-shot'

Comment: Would it look significantly better if I do that? Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I added a 'one-pass' version - it really doesn't work so well. You're going to have to do it in separate passes for each significant area.

Comment: Having the screen itself pretty much washed out doesn't hurt the overall image. Trying to compensate it at the same time as everything else hurts more than leaving it alone. My rough attempt at the entire area is based on getting the same guy to look about OK after the tweaks.

Comment: What I had in mind was to [reduce the intensity of the projected screen](https://i.imgur.com/Y4ajjWe.jpg). I guess for better results, would have to work on the screen and each person separately and combine results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of time on your hands, and have lots of skill, (I have neither), you could make some progress in improving the photo just by darkening selected areas, and using a "healing brush" to hide some of the defects.

Here is my results after about 10 mins playing around. 
[image] 
[image]